# How to suppresss Python Toolbox from adding output datasets to the map

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, python-toolbox

I wrote a Python Toolbox and would like to suppress it from adding output datasets to the active map. Below a minimal example (not the actual toolbox):

```py
import arcpy
from typing import List

class Toolbox(object):

    def __init__(self):

        self.label = "Toolbox"
        self.alias = "Toolbox"

        self.tools = [Tool]
```

```py
class Tool(object):

    def __init__(self):

        self.label = "Tool"
        self.description = "Tool Skeleton"

    def getParameterInfo(self) -> List[arcpy.Parameter]:

        output_feature_classes = arcpy.Parameter(
            name="output_feature_classes",
            displayName="Output Feature Classes",
            datatype="DEFeatureClass",
            parameterType="Derived",
            direction="Output",
            multiValue=True,
        )

        return [output_feature_classes,]

    def isLicensed(self) -> bool:
        return True  # always licensed
    
    def execute(self, parameters: List[arcpy.Parameter], messages):
        
        # arcpy.env.addOutputsToMap = False

        result = do_something()

        # make available for next tool
        parameters[0].value = result.feature_classes

        return result
```

`arcpy.env.addOutputsToMap = False` does apparently only work when used directly in the Python window or from a Notebook in ArcGIS Pro.

> `arcpy.env.addOutputsToMap` 
> The tool's resulting output datasets will be added to the application display. The property is only applicable when used directly in the Python window or from a Notebook in ArcGIS Pro. (https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/classes/env.htm)

**How can I suppress ArcGIS Pro from adding my output to the active map** if this is the only tool (or the last tool of a model) being run?

(I am aware of that if I use the tool in a model, I can configure if add or not add intermediate output to the map. I am also aware of that there is a global setting in Options.)

Note: The return value of `do_something()` is a `namedtuple` and its property `feature_classes` is an array of created feature classes. The code behind `do_something()` is completely decoupled from the Python toolbox.

Comment: Can you expand your code sample and show a real example of what the function do_something() is doing. By obfuscating your code the issue may lie within that function?

Comment: Do you absolutely need it to be a parameter? The last time I looked at this scenario there was nothing more that could be done than you've discovered. (Maybe things have changed). But generally, if something is a parameter, the app is going to add it to the map on execution unless the global GP setting has been turned off.

Comment: @KHibma, originally I didn't have a derived output parameter but if I'd like to use the result in a model, I wouldn't able to do so. If the answer to my question is that it's not possible, that's also an answer and I can stop searching for a solution. ;)

Comment: @Hornbydd, the return value of do_something() is a namedtuple and its property feature_classes is an array of created feature classes. The code behind do_something() is completely decoupled from the Python toolbox.

Comment: Well - if you're using your PYT as a sub-tool to a model, and within the model this output  IS NOT a **model parameter**, then I'd expect that it **not** be added to the display. But you're right, you need the PYT to have a parameter to make it chainable in the model. (just don't put the "P" on it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your output is a derived parameter, it will by displayed accordingly to the environnement variable `arcpy.env.addOutputsToMap` from the active map or from an other tool/model that contains your tool script.

You **cannot** set this option directly in your tool script with a derived parameter.